# Are there any beasts eligible for the druid's Wild Shape feature that have Legendary or Lair Actions?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, druid, actions, wild-shape

The Druid's [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) class feature states, in part:

> [...] If the creature has any legendary or lair actions, you can’t use them.

I do not recall ever seeing any creatures with Legendary or Lair Actions that were also eligible for the Druid's Wild Shape feature, even up to the 20th-level Moon Druid's selection of CR 6 beasts.

Do *any* such beasts exist in official publications, such that this rule would need to be applied?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### There are currently no eligible beasts with Legendary or Lair Actions.

It must be the case that this rule exists as a future-proofing measure and reminder, as it echoes the ["Legendary Creatures"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#LegendaryCreatures) section of the introduction to the *Monster Manual*, which states:

> If a creature assumes the form of a legendary creature, such as through a spell, it doesn’t gain that form’s legendary actions, lair actions, or regional effects.

There are currently no CR 6 or lower beasts with Legendary or Lair Actions. These searches on D&D Beyond would return any eligible creatures, but yield no results:

- [Beasts with Legendary Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=2&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=t&filter-is-mythic=&filter-has-lair=)
- [Beasts with Lair Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=2&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-is-mythic=&filter-has-lair=t)

And finally, the moon Druid’s elemental forms also lack Legendary and Lair Actions.

Comment: What about Mythic actions?

Comment: @nick012000 No, the lowest CR Mythic monster is the undead Dullahan from *Van Richten’s Guide* at CR 10.